# Layout preview and actual device do not match

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, xml-layout

I don't know why this is happening. I bet it's something real simple but I could not figure out why. I have a comment activity with a Relative Layout as a parent and a RecyclerView as well as a Linear Layout (with 2 children: an edit text and a submit button) as children. my layout.xml is as follow

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_comment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.erik.appname.CommentActivity">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="470dp"
    android:id="@+id/posted_comments">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/write_comment"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/posted_comments"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <EditText
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:background="@drawable/input_outline2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textPersonName|textMultiLine"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:hint="Comment..."
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:maxLength="100"
        android:id="@+id/current_comment" />

    <ImageButton
        android:src="@drawable/submit"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_outline2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/current_comment"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

this is what I got from the preview (which I want it to look like)
[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1we1.jpg)

while this is the screenshot from the actual device [real device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASP3k.jpg)

why are the edittext and button below the recyclerview behave that way?

I've tried many things such as wrapping everything in Linear Layout, wrapping the RelativeLayout in a Linear Layout and the Linear layout containing the edit text and button in another and tried to stack them up and use layout_weight to determine the proportion... can't seem to figure out the correct way to do it.

Many thanks for the help to come!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified your `RecyclerView` height to `android:layout_height="470dp"`, which is limited to `470dp` and after taking the predefined height it will leave the rest for the bottom `LinearLayout`. Defining hard code height is not a good idea. Try to remove the `height` and `width` of the `RecyclerView` to `match_parent` it will work.

Solved code [Edit with your next values]:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_comment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/posted_comments"
    android:layout_above="@+id/write_comment">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/write_comment"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <EditText
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textPersonName|textMultiLine"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:hint="Comment..."
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:maxLength="100"
        android:id="@+id/current_comment" />

    <ImageButton
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/current_comment"
        />


</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: superb it worked! I tried upvoting but unfortunately I still have some reps to go before I could do so. Thanks for the help Sir!